# get info from XML with CodeIgniter

Tags: xml, database, codeigniter

I want get the content from a XML file

for example this xml code for after insert in the database, but first I want how get the content

```
<users>
<user>
<name>Paco</name>
<surname>Lopez</surname>
<image1>image.jpg</image1>
<image2>image2.jpg</image2>
</user>
</users>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far to get the information you want?  What format are you expecting it to come out in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php SimpleXML

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("yourxml.xml");
echo $xml->name . "<br>";
echo $xml->surname . "<br>";
echo $xml->image1 . "<br>";
echo $xml->image2;
?>
```

You can find more about it here:

> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp